# How to compare data outputs of two different git commits

Tags: git, testing, github, automated-tests

I have a Github project that outputs a csv file. I want to make sure the csv output is the same after refactoring the code.

Currently, I do a manual check - but the overhead is getting to be too much.

Is there a standard way for comparing outputs across different git branches/commits?

Suppose we have a Master and Dev branch. My current idea is to have a script that:

- checkouts master
- runs program, saves output file
- checkouts dev
- runs program, saves output file
- compares to two output files

Is this an appropriate method for doing so? Is there anything I should be wary of?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That sounds like begging for a test, a unit test or an integration test. And you might calculate a hash (sha1, sha256, md5) so that you don't have to keep the whole output file under git.

Let me elaborate a little bit. You set up test scripts (there are many frameworks for this) where you run your application and compare outputs... you expect this file to remain the same all the time. If you hash it on your test, you can compare the hash with the *expected* hash. if the hash does not match, then the test failed. Then whenever you want to commit something, you first make sure your tests (of which you have tests that check *every piece of the project*) pass. If one of them breaks (for example, the output of the file you expected changed, therefore the hash changes, therefore that test fails) you need to sit down to see what's going on, no need to go back and forth between revisions (unless you really need to, depending on circumstances).

Comment: Thanks for pointing me in the right direction. Hashing will definitely simplify the process as I do not want to keep the entire output file stored in git.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there's a proper way to compare in git. But you can do it by comparing the outputs in command prompt.
And usually outputs are gitignored in a project

```
diff [options] File1 File2
```

Comment: Thank you. This doesn't help streamlining the process, but it will help when the tests fail.

Comment: U can look online for software that specifically cater for identify difference in files